# using primefaces extensions (inputNumber)

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

i'm new in `primefaces` word , and i need to use `primefaces` extensions (`inputNumber`)

in the XHTML file I add the taglib :

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

when adding the jar :

```
primefaces-extensions-0.6.3;
```

I have an error : `La ressource demandée n'est pas disponible.`

When removing it, the application works but the `inputNember` doesn't show and I get this
error:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions declared with prefix pe but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

Comment: How you add "primefaces-extensions-0.6.3" ?

Comment: i just add the jar primefaces-extensions-0.6.3 to the lib folder.

Comment: this is the error i got : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

Comment: You need to add commons-lang jar file.

Comment: i add the common-lang3.jar and it works ^_^ thank youa a lot

Comment: You should answer your question to close it.

Comment: i tried to do it but i have the msg : Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: You shoud mark @Serkan Arıkuşu's answer as answer to close this question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To work with primefaces extensions i should add to the XHTML file the taglib:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

and to the lib folder two jars:

```
primefaces-extensions-0.6.3.jar
common-lang3.jar.
```

that is all.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using maven for your dependencies, the required entry is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This will add the required dependencies for primefaces extensions.

If you are not using maven, then you should follow the [Getting Started](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started#other-users)  guide for "other users" and add all the necessary jars

Comment: @Ghizlane Ghizlanee: you shoud mark Serkan Arıkuşu's answer as answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, one maven dependencies is missing !

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Attention: currently "commons" is with S at end

At 2016.12.24, the version of extension can now be 6.0.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to Rong Nguyen and Ghizlane La

Last remark

I have encouter some problems (error message in Chrome indicating that some ressources are missing) because the versions used for Primefaces and PrimefacesExtension end Commons-lang3 are not compatible !

But I have found that the following combination work correclty for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope that will be useful for others :-)