# JSF/Primefaces: How to make digit 9 a constant in Inputmask tag?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mask, jsf-2.2, input-mask

I want to add a inputmask which is supposed accept phone numbers in standard format. I want to give "input mask" for standard phone number format e.g: +92 321 9388233. So how to give +92 as a constant in mask? The digit 9 is not behaving as constant. how to make digit 9 constant.

Comment: Maybe you can try it with a simple `<h:inputText>` and validate it with a given regex  on server side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape Number 9 in p:inputmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913451/escape-number-9-in-pinputmask)

Answer (score 0):

Digit 9 is defined as a mask for all digits. If you want it as a constant, you can try writing your own regular expression like this:

```
<p:inputMask>
    <pe:keyFilter regEx="\\+92[0-9 ]+" />
</p:inputMask>
```

**Update**

I found better solution, since this one doesn't work.

You can redefine mask definitions in JavaScript. Just add this script to your file:

```
$.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
$.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-9]';
```

And now your mask for digits will be letter `d` and not number `9`. So, this can be your mask:

```
<p:inputMask mask="+92 ddd ddddddd" />
```

Comment: This ain't working! <br/> `<p:inputMask  id="mnum" value="#{indexManagedBean.mobilenum}" mask="+92-999-9999999" >` <br/>
     `<pe:keyFilter regEx="\\+92[0-9 ]+" />` <br/>
     `</p:inputMask>`

Comment: Don't use mask attribute, just the filter.

Comment: Yae I still not working! if I remove the mask, no any mask appears in the text field then!

Comment: Did you include PrimeFaces Extensions?

Comment: You mean prime faces libraries? @Alexander

Comment: No, `<pe:keyFilter>` is provided by PrimeFaces Extensions. You need to include `xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"` in your xhtml to use it. Also put the jar in your lib folder. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015302/using-primefaces-extensions-inputnumber

Comment: Yes I have included this extension @alexander

Comment: @RabiaNazkhan Did you consider the attempt with an `<h:inputText>`?

Comment: No, I used <p:inputText>

Comment: I edited the answer and added another solution since the first one doesn't work.

Comment: @Crepi What if one doesn't want to use javascript? As I am not allowed to use it by my teacher!

Comment: Since Primefaces uses jquery library for this mask, I think this is the only way. Without javascript, maybe you could just print plain text "+92" followed by input for the rest of the digits (+92<p:inputMask mask="999 9999999" />)... It will be clear to user that they don't have to enter "+92", and you just do it in back-end for every input...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-inputmask='"mask": "+\\92999-9999999"' data-mask />
```

Just add \\ before 9 and this resolves your issue and will add a constant value like +92 at the start of a text.