# Escape Number 9 in p:inputmask

Tags: primefaces, escaping, jsf-2.2, input-mask

I want to prepend +90 (Turkey's phone code) to every phone numbers a user enters. For that reason I am using a mask like this:

```
<p:inputMask
    id="homePhone"
    value="#{personController.model.homePhone}"
    mask="+90 (999) 999-9999"
    size="20"
    converter="converterPhone" />
```

But displays it like this: `+_0 (___) ___-____`

However, I want it to look like this: `+90 (___) ___-____` `<!-- pay attention to 9 -->`

Is there a way to escape the first `9` like this: `mask="+\90 (999) 999-9999"`?

Thank you all...

Comment: doess it work ?

Comment: @Billy Hope, wouldn't it make a system-wide change? I would like to make the least impact (don't wanna effect other devs' code). But it would be nice to have another char (maybe * or #) to represent all digits, instead of 9, though.

Comment: i don't know how it could effect other dev's code, as long as you use javacript only on your own code, anyway # is a good choice, goodluck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number 9 is used as mask for all the digits, if you want to use 9, change the mask using JavaScript, by redefining x as mask :

```
$.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
$.mask.definitions['x'] = '[0-9]';
```

Now you can use x as mask,  :

```
<p:inputMask mask="+90(xxx) xxx-xxxx" id="homePhone"  />
```

Comment: It works like a charm (I used # instead of x since i represent x for extensions). Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

```
const phoneMask = new Inputmask("+886(xxx)xxx-xx-xx");

phoneMask.definitions.x = phoneMask.definitions['9'];
delete phoneMask.definitions[9];

phoneMask.mask(someElement);
```

Comment: Hi Vitalik and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask you not to answer just with only code in the future please. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. [See here for help answering.](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your newly mask is acting strange and replaces some static chars with the mask, then there is a definition which uses the char as symbol. To solve this you need to **double escape the char**.

Comment: Hi Luca, could you provide an example of how I would double escape the char please? Thanks.